# Is there a quick way to force Pycharm to refresh docker-compose cache?

Tags: docker-compose, pycharm

I have Pycharm working with docker-compose pretty well, but every time I want to change my docker-compose.yml file, I have to "invalidate cache and restart" or change the file name to bust Pycharm's cache of the file. It's pretty frustrating, and I keep forgetting that I'll be using an old docker-compose when I recompile. Anyone have a better way to force refresh?

- you can see the path to the cached file at the top of the console when running:

> /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /Users/{user}/Projects/project/docker-compose.yml -f /Users/{user}/Library/Caches/PyCharm2018.2/tmp/docker-compose.override.129.yml up

Answer (score 1):

This one's my own fault, I forgot that Pycharm would be using the run command from the debugger configuration, not the one from my docker-compose. Remember to update both.